# Only print out first row (file i/o)

Tags: c

```
FILE* fp;
errno_t err;
err = fopen_s(&fp, "hello.txt", "r");

int num;
int i;    

printf("Enter the num : ");

scanf_s("%d", &num);


i = 1;

num = getc(fp);

while (i <= num)

{

    putc(num, stdout);

    num = getc(fp);

    i++;

}
```

I want to print out 'num'th line, but it only prints out the first line.
No matter what number i is, only the first line is output.

+)
Sim no.,Masked,8AM
1,Y,Home,Library
2,Y,Home,Pizza
3,Y,Home,Home

this is hello.txt

when I enter the '3', I want to print out 3,Y,Home,Home
but it only print out Sim no.,Masked,8AM

Comment: This is not valid C code. Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: By "first row" do you mean "up to a particular character"? If so, what character?

Comment: `scanf_s("%d", &num); num = getc(fp);` What do you intend that to do? The `getc` overwrites the `num` value read by the `scanf_s` before it is ever used. And what is a "row"? Please give exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: `fopen_s()`?  `scanf_s()`?  Just say no to [Microsoft's nonstandard, non-portable](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations) implementations of the optional Annex K of the C standard.  The "deprecated" warnings you get from MSVC are (if you're willing to give Microsoft the benefit of the doubt given they're pushing Microsoft-specific non-portable code in what looks just like [vendor lock in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in)) misleading.  Just use `fopen()` and `scanf()`.  They **just as safe** while being portable, fully-compliant C.

Comment: Many errors, but like I said, you are overwriting `num` before it is even used. So the entered number (`3` in the example) is immediately lost. And then you constantly overwrite `num` in the loop whilst also using it as the loop condition. Suggest you do basic debugging by running your program in a debugger. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

There is so much wrong with what you posted, that it's easier to just start over.  First, do *not* read parameters from stdin.  (Imagine if grep worked that way, and you had to enter the pattern to search for as the first line of input!? It would render the tool nearly useless.)  Just do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int count = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1;
        int line = 1;
        int c;
        while( ( c = getchar()) != EOF && line <= count ) {
                if( line == count ) {
                        putchar(c);
                }
                if( c == '\n') {
                        line += 1;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

If you want to include code to open a file, that's easy enough, but you should get in the habit of writing filters and use the shell for redirections.